# Enable the disabled underlying window

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Sometimes in the Windows OS, a program is able to open a new window which disables it's underlying window. Closing the newly opened window of course re-enables the first window. I want to enable the underlying window without closing the newly opened window with Autohotkey.

I made a gif which shows the situation perfectly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df4Fm.jpg

I thought I might be able to pull this off with [window styles](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Styles.htm) and [window extended styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/extended-window-styles), so here's what I tried:

```
^!e::
MouseGetPos,,, WindowUnderMouse
WinSet, Style, -0x8000000, ahk_id WindowUnderMouse
return
```

But it didn't work. I also did a lot of googling on this, but I didn't know what would be the proper keywords so I didn't find anything. Any idea how to accomplish this?

---

Some keywords for google:

<sub>How to make a modal window modeless
How to enable a disabled window
How to make a palette window
How to make a modal window a palette window
How to enable parent window
Child window disabling parent window</sub>

https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/49376-making-a-gui-dialog-modal/
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm

Comment: That's called a "modal" window, btw.

Comment: I feel like this is going to be handled in the application itself, not really a windows piece that AHK could access right?

Comment: Seems so, I can't change the window styles, although ErrorLevel returns 0 which means success, I used this Window Style Checker to see what's the difference between a modal and modeless (palette) window, but changing them as I said doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know if the idea could work or not but it's missing the percent signs: ahk_id %WindowUnderMouse%

Comment: @scso wow it worked :o Thank you

Comment: Related question (not specific to AHK): [Unmodalize Dialogs](https://superuser.com/q/1560070/652023)